# GParted LiveCD: Is there a version with a 64-bit kernel?

Tags: kernel, grub, 64bit, chroot, gparted

I'm trying to chroot with the GParted LiveCD onto an existing 64-bit system, attempting to fix grub.

Comment: Does it necessarily need to be the GParted Live-CD? If not, you can use another one, like [grml](http://grml.org/download/) which is more powerful and has 64-bit version.

Comment: I'll try grml out, looks good.

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit GParted CD can resize partitions with 64-bit OS'es on them, no problem.

Comment: yes, but a 32 bit kernel can't chroot into a 64-bit userland.

Answer (score 1):

I've never found one.  I use clonezilla as a rescue CD (and network-boot image), and that DOES have a 64-bit version.

If you want 64-bit gparted live, you'll have to make your own, just replacing the kernel with a 64-bit kernel will be enough - it will be able to run the 32-bit userland on the gparted ISO.

BTW, when you do manage to chroot into your system you will need to bind-mount /dev, /sys, /proc (and optionally /dev/pts) into the chroot environment so that grub-install will have access to the info it needs to re-install into the MBR.

If your target system is mounted under /target, something like this will do the job:

`for i in dev proc sys dev/pts ; do mount -o bind /$i /target/$i ; done`

I have my netbootable clonezilla image configured to set that up as an alias called 'prepare-chroot-target' so I don't have to remember it :)

Comment: Yup, I won't forget mounting the other parts! 

The thing is that I really like having gparted on a rescue disc too, along with gdisk and all the disc utilities. I guess I'll just try to make my own.